# Install Rust on a 32 bit CentOS 7 server through SSH

Tags: ssh, rust, x86, centos7

I'm trying to install Rust on a 32 bit CentOS 7 server through SSH. I run this command suggested [here](https://www.mvps.net/docs/how-to-install-rust-on-centos/):

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

This command never finishes, and the server machine CPU fan goes high speed. Eventually, the server machine screen becomes black with keyboard lights getting on and off (blinking) repeatedly.

Is the problem due to the fact that the server is 32 bit? Is there any other possibility?

### Update

The kernel panic occurred multiple times, for example when trying to run `cargo run` as described here:

[kernel bug at kernel/auditsc.c:1532](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66741177/3405291)

Comment: Perhaps you could try downloading and running one of the standalone installers yourself?  https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html contains a download for a i686-unknown-linux-gnu build. Download and extract the .tar.gz and it contains an install.sh script which has a --verbose option. That might get you started.

Comment: @amo-ej1 Nice idea, I'm going to try =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@amo-ej1 comment worked.

Offline installers are available [here](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#standalone-installers). Just downloaded the `i686-unknown-linux-gnu` file `tar.gz` for *nightly*. Installed by running the `install.sh` script inside it with `--verbose` option.

[image: Table]